# Mutliple timezones in Postgres database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I think I want to store two different datetime attributes in my model, one client local time one UTC in my postgres database.  From what I understand, rails prefers that everything be written as one time zone making my job frustrating.

How do I do this with rails and/or why shouldn't I do this with rails?

The reason why I think this needs to be done is because I can display the local time to the user and use the UTC for sorting and charting.

Comment: Here is a blog post i wrote on rails timezones, might be of help - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

you can convert UTC time to local time using. For eg, if the local timezone is 'Alaska'

```
time_from_database.in_time_zone("Alaska")
```